# Javascript appendchild onclick not wiring up

Tags: javascript, web

I have an issue, happening in IE and Chrome...I am creating an autocomplete `text box`, using JSON values...

It is going as planned, apart from something I cannot work out...I am trying to wire an `onclick` up to each new span element that I am creating before appending it to the main autocomplete `div`.

```
 var deserialized = JSON.parse(json);
            for (var el in deserialized) {
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                var txtForSpan = document.createTextNode(deserialized[el]);
                span.appendChild(txtForSpan);
                span.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                elem.appendChild(span);
            }
            elem.style.display = "inline-block";
```

I have tried:

```
span.onclick = function(){alert("hi");}
```

and also:

```
span.addEventListener('click', function() {alert("hi");});
```

and even:

```
span.onclick = alertMe;
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Many Thanks.

Comment: And errors in the console?

Comment: Can you add it to a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/wc4ddjtz/ what are you doing that is different?

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone...

epascarello...feel slightly silly...thanks for the fiddle....I have an onblur event on my textbox that hides the autocomplete...onblur must be firing before the onclick gets a chance to fire on the span...DOH...thanks for the help again...going to have to look for another way around that...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses everyone, epascarello, your answer helped me work out what was wrong.

It turns out that the 'onblur' event, which I have on my textbox, is firing before the onclick of the appended spans.

To get round this, I have used a small timeout before the onblur event fires in order to let onclick fire first....not ideal, but it works pretty well...

Textbox:

```
            onblur="hide()"
```

Which calls:

```
            function hide(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                var elem = document.getElementById("completebox");
                elem.style.display = "none";
                elem.textContent = "";
            }, 300);}}
```